# nhibernate fluent to conformist mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

In nhibernate fluent mapping I used this

```
HasMany(x => x.Children).KeyColumn("ParentId");
References(x => x.ParentCategory).Column("ParentCategoryId").Cascade.SaveUpdate();
```

how this can be reprsented using nhib. mapping by code (conformist)?

```
I use Bag(x=>x.Childred, a=>{ a.OneToMany(); })
```

but I don't know how to set `ParentId` as Key column and how to represent `References` line from above line.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even I strongly suggest you to read at least [this](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/nhibernates-mapping-by-code-first.html) you can try to map `ParentCategory` with something like this

```
public class PageMap : ClassMapping<Page>
{
    public PageMap()
    {
       ..
       ManyToOne(x => x.ParentCategory, m =>
            {
                m.Cascade(Cascade.All);
                m.NotNullable(true);
            });

    }
}
```